# Arranging output by comparing with inputs

Tags: c++, sorting

I have two datasets like below:

set1:    `57.5276        55.3756        24.2798        54.5989`

and

set2:    `55.1118        55.004         24.824         57.1398`

Now I want to arrange the second set such that it matches closest to the first set (I mean `57.1398  55.1118  24.824   55.004` this order). 
How Can I do that in C++.

Comment: I removed the database tag, since your question does not seem to directly have anything to do with databases.

Comment: Calculate distances (ie. absolute value of substraction) between all numbers in set1 to set2 and choose the closest number in set1 for each number in set2?

Comment: What are the sizes of the data sets in question? Are you looking to optimize for some specific metric (CPU time, memory consumption?)? Should the first set remain unaltered and in the same order after the computation?

Comment: Question is to broad. Some more information is required... E.g. Have the sets always same size? How should set2 be handled; is a value to consider "consumed" after beeing choosen, or should it be the overall closest? What if two or more values have the same distance? What if two or more values have same distance to different values in set1?

Answer (score 0):

Arrange the second set such that it is ordered in the same way as the first set.

More specifically, the first set goes from the greatest number (`57.5276`) to the second greatest number (`55.3756`) to the fourth greatest to the third greatest.

Arrange the second set in the same way. Greatest (`57.1398`), second greatest (`55.004`), fourth greatest (`24.824`), third greatest (`57.1398`) in that order. This would minimize the average difference between items of the same index.

Programatically a simple way to implement this would be to sort both sets, then to find the sorted index of each number in the first set and arrange the second set in that same order.

Comment: Hi, the problem is I should not change the arrangement of the first set.

Comment: Sure, so for each element in the first set, look at all the other elements and see how many elements are less than that one. That number is your desired index. Or you can just create a separate duplicate set and sort that.

Answer (score 0):

Matching "closest" should be specified a little better. That could be, e.g., "minimum squared error", "minimum absolute error", "maximum correlation", which all would give different results.

Depending on what is meant with "closest", you may have to go through all permutations of set2, which would be expensive. If you want to go with the "sort both sets" solution, then a possible way to achieve this in c++ while retaining the order of the first set is to create a vector of indices into set1 and sorting this based on the values in set1

```
std::vector<double> set1{{57.5276,55.3756,24.2798,54.5989}};
std::vector<size_t> set1index(set1.size());
std::iota(set1index.begin(), set1index.end(), 0);
std::sort(set1index.begin(), set1index.end(), [&](size_t a, size_t b){return set1[a] < set1[b];});
```

You can then sort set2 and use the indices to recreate the order of set1 with the values of set2.